# AMP version of entire website

Tags: seo, usability, amp

I read about Google's AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) and I think it is a nice initiative. But I can't really determine the use of AMP for our website, since to me it seems more for article and product pages.

So my question is, will we benefit SEO and UX wise, for having AMP pages for our whole website?

We are a digital communication and web bureau and we sell services like web development, SEO etc. and we have a blog as well.

Answer (score 3):

AMP is about making pages load faster so the use case so far is for reading articles / static content only.

It will give a slight ranking boost from Feb 2016 but I wouldn't worry just yet.

Page speed is a really important factor from a UX point of view though.

If you don't have huge resources use AMP if you have static stuff (text/IMG).

You should really consider streamlining your HTML/CSS/JavaScript and making your site as a whole perform better.

I would suggest looking at chrome dev tools and working with your developers. Your aim should be to make your site load as close to a second (or less = better) as possible.

Get rid of JavaScript your not using, make sure you concatenate and minify files, load HTML, CSS first only load JavaScript when needed. Parallelize images.

You don't need AMP. Focus on performance of your site, and it isn't required.

Comment: Thank you :) We are all ready implementing CDN caching and high performance for the website. We hope it to load in 1-2(max) seconds. But if Google fevors the site with AMP structure just because it is AMP, it would be nice to know :)

Comment: The simplest answer is they will favour sites that load faster, google won't favour you because you are specifically using AMP as it would be anti-competitive. If you choose to use that stripped back look then yes you will be favoured but there's little to no branding on those pages which might be important to your company.

Comment: I see, thank you mate :) I think we will just focus on performance and keep our identity :P

Comment: See how it matures, you obviously do use branding which is really important for your business.